# using heading tags moves div downwards

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a header for a personal cv site, and for some reason using heading tags `<h2></h2> <h3></h3>` moves the parent div `.header` downwards. When I try to move the headings using margin-top it just moves the whole div again. I am using [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) (tried removing it but nothing changed) along with a google font I chose. Otherwise all code is posted in the fiddle below. Can somebody explain why this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Miha Šušteršič</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500,700&subset=latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="header">
                <h2> Miha Šušteršič </h2>
                <h3> Web Developer </h3>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section id="menu">
        </section>
        <section id="skills">
        </section>
        <section id="porfolio">
        </section>
        <footer>            
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
/********************************************
SPLOŠNO
********************************************/

body {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    line-height: 120%;
    margin: 0;
}



/********************************************
HEADER
********************************************/

.header {
    width: 100%;
    background:
        linear-gradient(
            to bottom,
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)
            ),
        url("../images/header.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.header h2 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 3em;
}
.header h3 {
    color: #eaf1fb;
}


/********************************************
TABLET ADJUSTMENTS
********************************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `margin` on your header tags in the CSS:

```
.header h2, .header h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: This positioned the div correctly. I've also added the space I wanted up top using padding. Ty